# Random newline character in column list of dataframe resulting in KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of which I'm trying to get only a subset of the columns and then  renaming said columns.

```
req_cols = ['targetName','suiteName','configName','testName','actualResult_1','actualResult_2','explanation_1']

df = df[req_cols].rename(columns={'targetName':'tgt', 'suiteName':'suite', 'configName':'config', 'testName':'test', 'actualResult_2':'iresult', 'actualResult_1':'gresult', 'explanation_1':'explanation'})
```

I get this error however.

```
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['targetName' 'suiteName' 'configName' 'testName' 'actualResult_1'\n 'actualResult_2' 'explanation_1'] not in index"
```

Why does this random newline character appear in this column list?

Comment: How do you create `df` ? Is separator `sep='\s+'` if use `read_csv` ?

Comment: I actually create df by directly reading from a database using `read_sql`.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` before `df = df[req_cols]` ?

Comment: @jezrael No, didn't use that statement.

Comment: I know, please use it for return real columns names ;)

Comment: @RahulG jezreal meant to say, what's the output of `print(df.columns.tolist())` before the line containing `.rename` function

Comment: This is the output of the print statement:
`['id_1', 'targetName', 'suiteName', 'configName', 'testName', 'result_1', 'actualResult_1', 'explanation_1', 'file_1', 'id_2', 'result_2', 'actualResult_2', 'explanation_2', 'file_2']`.

Comment: @RahulG - I have no idea, `keyerror` means some column names not matched, but here all columns names are in `req_cols`.  It is really weird.